# Multiplication of large numbers yields wrong value

Tags: c++, integer-overflow, long-long

I have the code

```
long long x = 200000 * 200000;
cout << x << endl;
```

it outputs 1345294336
I've tried converting to a string and outputting each digit, and it still outputs the same thing

Comment: You want to check out the [numeric limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) of your machine of choice. Data types cannot hold artificially large numbers. Once you reach that limit, your number overflows.

Comment: `1345294336` (a.k.a. `0x502F9000`)  happen to be the lower 32 bits of `40000000000` (.a..k.a. `0x9502F9000`),

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
long long x = 200000LL * 200000LL; 
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

note the "LL" suffix. To read more about using suffixes for numeric literals, visit the [Integer Literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) page on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal).

Comment: a=200000
b=200000
and i want to output a*b

Comment: Then use `static_cast<long long>(a) * static_cast<long long>(b)` (if they're not already large enough types).

Comment: @AlexanderYang: Instead of saying "it works" in a comment, what you do here on StackOverflow is accept the answer. You can also upvote it if you found it useful (sometimes that's not the same thing).

Comment: Do you have to cast both values? The other should get promoted to `long long`.

Comment: No, one is enough.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: One is enough, but casting only one introduces asymmetry which is would mystify the reader somewhat. This is pursuant to the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187457/what-is-the-principle-of-least-astonishment).